# Transform URL string into normal string in Python (%20 to space etc)

Tags: python, string

Is there any way in Python to transform this `%CE%B1%CE%BB%20` into this `αλ` which is its real representation?

Comment: What do you mean by "real representation"?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

For python 2:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> print urllib2.unquote("%CE%B1%CE%BB%20")
αλ
```

For python 3:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import unquote
>>> print(unquote("%CE%B1%CE%BB%20"))
αλ
```

And here's code that works in all versions:

```
try:
    from urllib import unquote
except ImportError:
    from urllib.parse import unquote

print(unquote("%CE%B1%CE%BB%20"))
```

Comment: For **Python 3**: `import urllib.request`         `urllib.request.unquote(...)`

Comment: urllib has now put unqote in the parse module `from urllib.parse import unquote` (https://git.ziirish.me/ziirish/burp-ui/issues/75)

Answer (score 11):

There are two encodings in play here. Your string has first been encoded as [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), then each byte has been [percent-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

To get the original string back you need to first unquote it, and then decode it:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> s = '%CE%B1%CE%BB%20'
>>> result = urllib.unquote(s).decode('utf8')
>>> print result
αλ
```

Note that you need a Unicode enabled console in order to display the value (if you get an error with the print statement, try running it in [IDLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE_%28Python%29)).

Comment: thanks a lot! decode('utf8') was useless to me, though. unquote(s) did the job!

Comment: But it does. Just tried it to be on the safe side (IDLE, py2.7)

Answer (score 4):

python 3 answer

```
import urllib 
urllib.parse.unquote('/El%20Ni%C3%B1o/')

'/El Niño/'
```

[source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html)

Comment: import urllib.parse not urllib